# Configuration of Django-admin fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I’m trying to adjust the following logic:

there is **field 1** - BooleanField and **field 2** - CharField, if field 1 = True, then field 2 is open for enter information.

Otherwise the information in field 2 is erased and the field is closed for input.

[image]

Now it is realized only at the level of the form of product creation through JS.
If you save the product and open it for editing, the field state is reset.

To save the status it is written as follows:

**Admin.py**

```
class SmartPhoneAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not kwargs.get('instance').sd:
            self.fields['sd_value'].widget.attrs.update({
                'readonly': True,
                'style': 'background: #050505;'
            })

    def clean(self):

        if not self.cleaned_data['sd']:
            self.cleaned_data['sd_value'] = None

        return self.cleaned_data
```

The problem is that the expression kwargs.get('instance') returns None and I get an error.

**attributeerror: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'sd'**

and i don't understand why instance = None.

Full code:

**Admin.py**

```
class SmartPhoneAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not kwargs.get('instance').sd:
            self.fields['sd_value'].widget.attrs.update({
                'readonly': True,
                'style': 'background: #050505;'
            })

    def clean(self):

        if not self.cleaned_data['sd']:
            self.cleaned_data['sd_value'] = None

        return self.cleaned_data

class SmartPhoneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    change_form_template = 'admin.html'
    form = SmartPhoneAdminForm
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):

        if db_field.name == 'category':
            return ModelChoiceField(Category.objects.filter(slug = 'smartphone'))

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    
admin.site.register(SmartPhone, SmartPhoneAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

**Models.py**

```
def get_product_url(obj, viewname):
    
    ct_model = obj.__class__._meta.model_name
    return reverse(viewname, kwargs = {'ct_model': ct_model, 'slug': obj.slug})

class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
class Product(models.Model):
    
    # in pixels
    MIN_WIDTH = 400
    MIN_HEIGHT = 400
    MAX_WIDTH = 2500
    MAX_HEIGH = 2500

    # in bytes
    MIN_IMAGE_SIZE = 1024
    MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 3145728

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 verbose_name = 'Категория',
                                 on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = '',verbose_name = 'Изображение')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Описание', null = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9,
                                decimal_places = 2,
                                verbose_name = 'Цена')
    
    def save(self, *agrs, **kwargs) -> None:

        image = self.image
        img = Image.open(image)

        if img.height <  self.MIN_HEIGHT or img.width <  self.MIN_WIDTH:
            raise MinResolutionException ('Разрешение изображения меньше минимального!')
        
        elif img.height > self.MAX_HEIGH or img.width > self.MAX_WIDTH:
            new_img = img.convert('RGB')
            resize_new_img = new_img.resize((2500,2500), Image.BILINEAR)
            file_stream = BytesIO()
            resize_new_img.save(file_stream,'JPEG', quality = 90)
            file_stream.seek(0)
            name = '{}.{}'.format(*self.image.name.split('.'))
            self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(file_stream,
                                              'ImageField',
                                              name,
                                              'jpeg/image',
                                              sys.getsizeof(file_stream),
                                              None)
        
        super().save(*agrs, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

class SmartPhone(Product):

    diagonal = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Диагональ')
    display_type = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Тип дисплея')
    resolution = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Разрешение экрана')
    aсcum_value = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Объем батареи')
    ram = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Оперативная память')
    sd = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Наличие SD карты')
    sd_value = models.CharField(max_length = 255,
                                verbose_name = 'Максимальный объем встраиваемой памяти',
                                null = True,
                                blank = True)
    main_cam_mp = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Главная камера')
    frontal_cam_mp = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Фронтальная камера')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return '{} : {}'.format(self.category.name, self.title)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return get_product_url(self, 'product_detail')
```

Googling and reading the documentation didn't help me :(

Comment: Forgot to specify: Django 4.2.3

Comment: When you *create* an instance, then `instance` is indeed `None`, it is only if you *update* that there is an item.

Comment: indeed that this implementation works with already created products, but throws an error when I try to create a new one.  It will be necessary to reconsider the logic ))